# Activate EAP-SIM/AKA by Android app without root

Tags: android, security, authentication

would like to know is it possible to activate or execute EAP-SIM/AKA procedure via an Android app. As far as I know, under SEEK project, it's possible to send APDU command to SIM. However, activiating EAP-SIM seems not possible.

Comment: Did you find any solution?